# How can I stop or turn off mobile operator notifications for SMS?

Tags: 8.1, sms

How can I turn off SMS notifications from my mobile operator? I get a notification each time I send a text and it is really annoying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do the following:

1. Open the Messaging app
2. Expand the app bar by tapping on "..."
3. Tap "Settings"
4. From there you can disable delivery confirmation for SMS and MMS messages

Answer (score 0):

Nokia 521
Click on the message icon

click on the three dots on the bottom right of the screen ...

Then click the settings

Then turn off confirmations in there

Comment: This seems to be what Indrek said to do back in March -- did you meant to clarify further?